# Merge two datasets based on unique distinct time intervals and then create a dataset with all unmatched values (in R)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate, stringr

I have two separate datasets: df1 and df2. I would like to create a new dataset, df3 that would match the endtime column of df1 with the sent column of df2 if the datetimes are within 20 seconds of each other. Lastly, I would like to create a final dataset that gives me all the values in the df2 dataset (sent/ID dataset) that did not match df1.

```
 df1

 endtime                     ID

 1/7/2020  1:35:08 AM         A
 1/7/2020  1:39:00 AM         B
 1/20/2020 1:45:00 AM         C



 df2

sent                         ID

1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM          E
1/7/2020  1:42:00 AM          F
1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM          G
1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM          E
```

This is my desired output for df3. There is only one row, because there are only two values that match the condition of being within 20 seconds of the endtime and sent columns.

```
endtime                  sent 

1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM      1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM
```

Desired output for unmatched values

```
sent 

1/7/2020  1:42:00 AM
1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM          
1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM
```

Here is the dput:

```
df1

structure(list(endtime = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1/10/2020 1:45:00 AM", 
"1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", "1/7/2020 1:39:00 AM"), class = "factor"), 
ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, 
 -3L))





 df2

 structure(list(sent = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM", 
 "1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:35:20 AM", "1/7/2020 1:42:00 AM"
 ), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
"F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

This is what I have tried:

I am thinking of performing a left join and matching the values, or I can use merge(), but the tricky part is matching the values with the conditional statement. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
     df3<-crossing(endtime = as.POSIXct(df1$endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), 
               sent = as.POSIXct(df2$sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) %>% 
     filter((endtime - seconds(20)) <= sent, 
     (endtime + seconds(20)) >= (sent)) %>%
     mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") %>%
     distinct(sent, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This works well, but I do not know how to find all the values in the df2 dataset that are essentially "left-over" and didn't have a match. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You could add an `ID` column to each original data.frame and the check which `ID`s are not in `df3` i.e. `df1$ID[!df1$ID %in% df3$ID, ]`...

Comment: good idea! @dario

Comment: Sure: `df1$ID <- 1:nrow(df1)`

Comment: But scrapp that, I only realized now that your `df3` doesn't lend itself to this solution,

Comment: If I might ask: Why is your date column formatted as a vector in your example data??

Comment: Hi Dario, shouldn't the above code include df2 as well or no?  df1$ID[!df1$ID %in% df3$ID, ]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but the 'unique ID' column solution won't work because `df3` is stripped of all other columns besides the date columns. See my answer below for a working solution. But the question regarding the dates that are used as factors remains (a lot of redundant formatting of the date columns happening in this code...)

Comment: ok thank you I am trying your solution now-so I have those formats in the code because whenever I performed a command, the layout would change to 2020-01-01 and I was wanting 01/01/2020 etc

Comment: But that's only the displayed date. Change that when **showing** the data, but for internal purposes leave it as date... But you are free to do as you please, it's your data ;)

Comment: Oh I think I understand, sort of a behind the scenes formatting going on there. Thank you

Comment: Hello @dario does the output display the AM/PM? I’m not seeing this when I run the code. For instance in df3 output, how do I display the AM/PM?

Comment: Hi Tanisha. Please read the comments below on the answer again (i explain there the problem with the original code and suggested two solutions). If you still have a question feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok I looked at this and was wondering, is the output for df3 suppose to show AM/PM?

Comment: The solution I suggested replaces the AM/PM representation of the datetime column with 24h notation for `df3`.

Comment: Oh I see ok- does this keep things more consistent I suppose?

Comment: The example you gave hat the `endtime` and `sent` column as a factor (a string representing a time in AM/PM format). in order to compare *time* intervals we had to re-cast it to a date-time type. For this we used the `as.POSIXct` function, i.e. `as.POSIXct(df1$endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" )`.

Comment: ok I see thank you

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a bit unclear. No, the change is not for consistency, actually it's a bit more inconsistent because df1 and df2 *still* use AM/PM. We had to made the change because there was a problem. The code you showed in your question had a bug where the AM/PM was not displayed. Just look at the output of df3. There are no AM or PMs..(The tibble which I show right at the start of my Edit in the answer shows that). This is a problem because this way we couldn't distinguish 11h and 23h!? Thats why I suggest the adapted code for df3 in my edit. To fix the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(list(endtime = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1/10/2020 1:45:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", "1/7/2020 1:39:00 AM"),class = "factor"),
                      ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(sent = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM", "1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:35:20 AM", "1/7/2020 1:42:00 AM"), class = "factor"),
                      ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("E", "F", "G"), class = "factor")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

## Edit:

I had to change the re-casting of the dates a bit since it did **not** show the "AM" and "PM" part of the datetime string:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  endtime                sent                  
  <chr>                  <chr>                 
1 "01/07/2020 01:35:08 " "01/07/2020 01:35:20 "
```

Before:

```
mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

After:

```
mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Adapted code to create `df3`:

```
df3<-crossing(endtime = as.POSIXct(df1$endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), 
              sent = as.POSIXct(df2$sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) %>% 
  filter((endtime - seconds(20)) <= sent, 
         (endtime + seconds(20)) >= (sent)) %>%
  mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") %>%
  distinct(sent, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

`df3` being now:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  endtime             sent               
  <chr>               <chr>              
1 01/07/2020 01:35:08 01/07/2020 01:35:20
```

Comment: Why are `sent` and `endtime` re-cast as strings here? Wouldn't you want them as date?? Because we are going to have to re-caste them **again** below.

## Suggested solution:

Identifying unmatched rows:

```
df1_unmatched <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(endtime = as.POSIXct(endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" )) %>% 
  filter(!endtime %in% as.POSIXct(df3$endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" ))

df2_unmatched <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(sent = as.POSIXct(sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  filter(!sent %in% as.POSIXct(df3$sent,format ="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" ))


df1_unmatched
```

Returns:

```
              endtime ID
1 2020-01-07 01:39:00  B
2 2020-01-10 01:45:00  C
```

And

```
df2_unmatched
```

Returns:

```
                 sent ID
1 2020-01-07 01:42:00  F
2 2020-01-20 01:55:00  G
3 2020-01-20 02:00:00  E
```

Comment: Ok I will try first thing tomorrow , thank you. Is there a way to show the unmatched sent times? I will troubleshoot this

Comment: There is still an bug in the code: Replace the line `mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") %>%` with `mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") %>%`

Comment: oh! I didn't have any errors while performing the command. Can you tell me what the bug is?

Comment: The date formatting in the code for `df3` didn't work correctly  because it did not print the "AM" or "PM" part (see code example right at beginning of my edit above -  there is **no** "AM" or "PM"!). That means that "01:00:00 AM" would have been the **same** as "01:00:00 PM". Which is **not** what we want?! The new code uses the 24-hour format and fixes this issue. But as already mentioned: I would strongly advice to do a cleanup on the multiple dates casting and re-casting in this code.

Comment: Ok, shouldn't we keep the %p?? isn't this what displays the AM/PM?

Comment: Ok thank you I will do all this in the morning. I still do not see the AM/PM in the return result for the sent. Thank you for all your help

Comment: My suggestions are: 1. (Probably best way) Clean up the date variables. Convert them **once** to date-times using `as.POSIXct` with arguments as in the code you wrote. Do not re-cast it as string. Ever ;). Adapt the remaining code accordingly. **OR** 2. Fix the line `mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") %>%`  by replacing it with `mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") %>%` (that's what Ii used it in my answer). If this is confusing consider reading up on `?as.POSIXct` and `?format`. The first is used to make strings to dates and the latter to do the reverse.

Comment: Ok I will try! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using non-equi in `data.table`:

```
df3 <-  df1[, c("st", "et") := .(endtime - 20L, endtime + 20L)][
    df2, on=.(st<=sent, et>=sent), nomatch=0L, .(ID1=x.ID, ID2=i.ID, endtime, sent)]
```

output:

```
   ID1 ID2             endtime                sent
1:   A   E 2020-01-07 01:35:08 2020-01-07 01:35:20
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, endtime := as.POSIXct(as.character(endtime),format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")]
setDT(df2)[, sent := as.POSIXct(as.character(sent), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")]
```